# Uncommenting a config line based on regex with string replace

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a config file with a bunch of URLs for repos that are commented out. I need to uncomment a specific one and thought sed would make it easy to match a regex then doing a string replace on that line.

I was wondering if my regex in correct for sed syntax or if the sed command is not correct?

```
mirrorRegex="^# http.*vendor.*distroARCH-1.1\/"
sed '/$mirrorRegex/s/# //' /etc/repos
```

Before:

```
# ftp://mirrors.example.com/distro/distroARCH-1.1/
# http://mirrors.example.com/distro/distroARCH-1.1/
# ftp://packages.vendor.org/distro/distro/distroARCH-1.1/
# http://packages.vendor.org/distro/distro/distroARCH-1.1/
# http://mirror.school.edu/pub/distro/distroARCH-1.1/
# http://system.site3.com/distroARCH-1.1/
```

After: What is expected.

```
# ftp://mirrors.example.com/distro/distroARCH-1.1/
# http://mirrors.example.com/distro/distroARCH-1.1/
# ftp://packages.vendor.org/distro/distro/distroARCH-1.1/
http://packages.vendor.org/distro/distro/distroARCH-1.1/
# http://mirror.school.edu/pub/distro/distroARCH-1.1/
# http://system.site3.com/distroARCH-1.1/
```

Comment: is this not what you expected?

Comment: @UriMikhli the second part is what I expected but it wasn't working anubhava pointed out that I was using single quotes which wasn't expanding the shell variable when sed was ran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use double quotes in order to expand shell variables:

```
sed "/$mirrorRegex/s/# //"
```

Comment: Wow I don't know why I didn't remember that. Thank you, don't I feel foolish. I'll accept this as the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like this to do the same:

```
awk '$0~var {sub(/^# /,x)}1' var="$mirrorRegex" file
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for showing me that. I figured awk would work as well I'm trying to learn sed and awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's|^#[[:blank:]]*\(http.*vendor.*distroARCH-1.1/.*\)|\1|' YourFile
```

use of other separator than default `/`  (`|` in this case) will help

and with variable version

```
Content='http.*vendor.*distroARCH-1.1/'
sed "s|^#[[:blank:]]*\(${Content}.*\)|\1|" YourFile
```